# Unable to see the data in mysql which is inserted using php and mysql queries

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, plesk

I have a registered a domain and I am using plesk panel to upload files everything is working cool but i cant see the data in the mysql database that i inserted using mysql queries with php into the database .I am not sure but why i cant see the data in the database created by me? do I need to do fill up or do anything before i view the data in the database i created.Please let me know this any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: try to insert data though phpmysqladmin n then try to view from php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing special you need to do to view the data. The problem is most likely with your php script for adding the data in the db. Have you checked that for errors?

You can also try running the sql queries directly from phpmypadmin just to make sure they are correct and then try again using php.